# Alphabetically Sort table and catagorize

Tags: jquery, html, sorting

Hello I am trying to make a table list, sorted and organized. 
My ideal setup will be a table where I just put names and it organizes them and puts them in the right category. 
Names starting with **A** will be put in the **A category**, while names starting with **B** will be put in **B category** and so on.

**My first** picture shows what I want(not sorted, just an example).
**My second** picture shows what I get when using JQuery code I found on other posts, i searched and found no examples which deal with categorizing.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL663gn5/1/)
The second picture is from the result of this fiddle.

This is the JQuery function I use for sorting

```
    var mylist = $('ul');
var listitems = mylist.children('li').get();
listitems.sort(function (a, b) {
    return $(a).text().toUpperCase().localeCompare($(b).text().toUpperCase());
})
 $.each(listitems, function (idx, itm) {
    mylist.append(itm);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks, all inputs greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help but feel there should be a better way, but this is the best I could come up with, currently (though it uses native JavaScript, rather than jQuery):

```
// retrieves the first <ul> from the document:
var mylist = document.querySelector('ul'),
    // retrieves the <li> children from that <ul>,
    // using Function.prototype.call, and Array.prototype.slice
    // to convert that NodeList into an Array:
    listitems = Array.prototype.slice.call(mylist.querySelectorAll('li'), 0),
    // an empty object, for later use:
    order = {},
    // elements, for later use:
    ul = document.createElement('ul'),
    li = document.createElement('li'),
    // a document fragment:
    fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
    // the assigned width for the sorted lists (adjust to taste):
    width = 100,
    // the offset (to set the node.style.left CSS property):
    offset = 0,
    // empty variables for use later:
    first,
    cloneUL,
    cloneLI;

// your original sort function, but using plain JavaScript, using
// node.textContent in place of jQuery's $(node).text()
listitems.sort( function (a, b) {
    return a.textContent.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.textContent.toUpperCase());
// chaining Array.prototype.forEach() to perform an action on
// each element of the sorted array:
}).forEach(function (li, index, arr) {
    // li: the first argument of the anonymous function is
    // is always the array-element (in this case the <li>),
    // index: the second argument is the index of the current
    // array-element (here unused),
    // arr: the third argument is the full array over which
    // we're iterating (here unused).

    // storing a reference to the first letter of the current <li>:
    first = li.textContent.charAt(0);

    // if there is no value for a given key (first) for the object
    // (order), we...
    if (!order[first]) {
        // ...create an empty array:
        order[first] = [];
    }

    // and then push the current <li> into that array:
    order[first].push(li);        
});

// here we use the for...in loop to iterate over the
// (not reliably ordered) properties of the array:
for (var letter in order){
    // using Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty() to
    // check that the current property (the letters, from
    // earlier) has been assigned deliberately (true) or
    // inherited from the prototype chain (false):
    if (order.hasOwnProperty(letter)){
        // cloning the li (from earlier) and
        // assigning it to the empty variable:
        cloneLI = li.cloneNode();
        // as above, with different variables:
        cloneUL = ul.cloneNode();

        // assigning the id of the created/cloned-<ul>:
        cloneUL.id = letter;

        // setting the left and width properties:
        cloneUL.style.left = offset + 'px';
        cloneUL.style.width = width + 'px';

        // appending the cloned-<ul> to the cloned-<li>:
        cloneLI.appendChild(cloneUL);

        // iterating over the sorted array of <li> elements
        // stored in the order[letter] properties:
        order[letter].forEach(function (li) {
            // appending each <li> in turn to the cloned-<ul>:
            cloneUL.appendChild(li);
        });

        // appending the cloned-<li> (containing the cloned-<ul>)
        // the created documentFragment:
        fragment.appendChild(cloneLI);

        // updating the offset, to prevent overlap of
        // the created-<li> elements:
        offset += width;
    }
}

// while the <ul> (mylist) has a firstChild:
while (mylist.firstChild) {
    // we remove that firstChild:
    mylist.removeChild(mylist.firstChild);
}
// appending the created-documentFragment to the
// now emptied <ul>:
mylist.appendChild(fragment);
```

```js
var mylist = document.querySelector('ul'),
  listitems = Array.prototype.slice.call(mylist.querySelectorAll('li'), 0),
  order = {},
  ul = document.createElement('ul'),
  li = document.createElement('li'),
  fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  width = 100,
  offset = 0,
  first,
  cloneUL,
  cloneLI;

listitems.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.textContent.toUpperCase().localeCompare(b.textContent.toUpperCase());
}).forEach(function(li) {
  first = li.textContent.charAt(0);
  if (!order[first]) {
    order[first] = [];
  }
  order[first].push(li);
});

for (var letter in order) {
  if (order.hasOwnProperty(letter)) {
    cloneLI = li.cloneNode();
    cloneUL = ul.cloneNode();
    cloneUL.id = letter;

    cloneUL.style.left = offset + 'px';
    cloneUL.style.width = width + 'px';

    cloneLI.appendChild(cloneUL);
    order[letter].forEach(function(li) {
      cloneUL.appendChild(li);
    });
    fragment.appendChild(cloneLI);
    offset += width;
  }
}

while (mylist.firstChild) {
  mylist.removeChild(mylist.firstChild);
}
mylist.appendChild(fragment);
```

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
}
ul,
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul {
  display: block;
}
ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
ul > li > ul {
  display: list;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
ul > li > ul > li {
  display: list-item;
}
li:nth-child(odd) > ul {
  background-color: #ffa;
}
li:nth-child(even) > ul {
  background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Ape</li>
  <li>Ace</li>
  <li>Ache</li>
  <li>Aart</li>
  <li>Ant</li>
  <li>A1</li>
  <li>Bear</li>
  <li>Beat</li>
  <li>Born</li>
  <li>Corpse</li>
  <li>Carp</li>
  <li>Cant</li>
  <li>Crane</li>
  <li>Crazy</li>
  <li>Computer</li>
</ul>
```

And a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oL663gn5/2/), to facilitate experimentation.

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push).
- [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).
- [`document.createDocumentFragment()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment).
- [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement).
- [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).
- [`Function.prototype.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call).
- [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style).
- [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild).
- [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode).
- [`Node.removeChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild).
- [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty).
- [`String.prototype.charAt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt).
- [`String.prototype.localeString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).
- [`String.prototype.toUpperCase()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperString).
- [`while ()` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while).

Comment: I kept trying with the Jquery without getting anything done. Your answer seems to get the job done, which is all that matters :) Couldn't find anything which came close to this so this is greatly appreciated, thanks a bunch :)

Comment: You're very welcome indeed, I'm glad to have been of some help! :)

Comment: Btw sry to bother again, but what do I do if I want to position D under A?
A, B, C <br> D, E, F </br> G... Basically have 3 categories in each row, then the next 3 categories </br>. Thx in advance and it's alright if it can't be done :).

Comment: I've commented out a few parts to allow that to happen, but I've not replaced the top-aligning parts. And I'm probably not going to have time to do so for a couple of days, now. Sorry. But here's the updated JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/oL663gn5/5/